# Rails 3.0.x send_file sending 404 HTML instead of the real file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, download

I have setup a route to handle a specific file download.

```
  match '/overview' => "pages#overview", :as => "da_overview"
```

in Pages#overview, I'm sending the file with this line

```
send_file File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'downloads', 'overview.pdf'), :type =>"application/pdf"
```

I've switched on the x-sendfile setting.

```
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

Also, I've installed and enabled mod_xsendfile module in the apache server. I have enabled it for my site as well.

```
XSendFile on
```

Still, when I hit the url http://mysite.com/overview, the browser is downloading `overview.pdf.html` and the HTML file says `404: Requested URL /overview not found on this server`

I've checked the file existence. The pdf file is /public/downloads directory. What configuration am i missing? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of mod_xsendfile that you're running you'll need to add one of the following after "XSendFile on" to give mod_xsendfile permissions to access files on your filesystem.

**mod_xsendfile 0.9:**

`XSendFileAllowAbove on`

**mod_xsendfile >0.9:**

`XSendFilePath "/path/where/files/you're/sending/are"`